# Codeblocks compiles but doesn't run executable

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have a new Codeblocks install with mingw32 compiler. Created new c++ console project with default hello world stuff and I hit F9 (Build and Run). Compiles without problems but doesn't run the executable. I created new entry under tools ...

[image]

... and when I execute it from the tools menu it opens the cb_console_runner and its all good.
So how do I configure Codeblocks to run my custom tools entry after building (when I hit F9)?

The funny thing is that I have already managed to do this but I forgot exactly how and now I'm unable to find the link.

Comment: This image is too small!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time but I figured out a workaround. The reason why Codeblocks didn't execute my program after Compile & run (F9) is because my projects compiler and IDE's default compiler didn't match. I used Mingw32 TDM and default was VC2005/2008. When setting former to default it started working without problems :)

[image]

So when You have 2 projects with different compilers and You develop them in parallel, it will get tedious very fast. It should probably use projects settings for this, not IDE's default.

Answer (score 0):

Putting another possible solution here for the occasional linux user who needs it:

The default terminal on settings might not be installed on your system. Install xterm or change the settings on codeblocks to use whatever you prefer (Konsole on KDE, for instance).